# How to implement cache busting for Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: .net, caching, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Currently, we are referencing JS and CSS assets in our Blazor Web Assembly application as following:

index.html

```
<link href="css/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CompnayName.ProjectName.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

...

```
<script src="js/shared/shared.min.js"></script>
```

Every time we make any changes to these files - we need to clear the browser cache on LIVE env to see the changes.

Is there any way to implement cache busting?

Answer (score 4):

Add a fake query parameter to the request and increment the version on publish.

```
<script src="js/shared/shared.min.js?version=1.3"></script>
```